# How to change name of LUKS encrypted partition?

Tags: 20.04, files, encryption, luks, udisks

I am using **ubuntu 20.04.2 (64bit)** on my dell laptop. I have three drive partition named as D,E and H. I have **enrypted D** and **E** with **LUKS**. Drives are encrypted well, but the drive-name I have set at the time of encryption doesn't show at Files. It shows up as **200GB Encrypted**. After mounting the drives and authenticating,the names shows up. But I want to show the drive-names [as **D-drive, E-drive**] instead of **200GB Encrypted**.
[image]
I have tried some methods but failed. If anyone has solution to this problem, please help.

Comment: Did you add a label or do you mount it as "D"/"E"?

Comment: Hello #Rinzwind, I have added labels as D-drive and E-drive using gparted, but it doesn't work